# Android Studio rendering problems after installing 64-bit version of windows

Tags: android, android-studio

I've installed a new android studio instance on my windows after upgrading to *64-bit Windows 10*.

I've tried to mess and look for answers for this render problem and couldn't find a solution.

This is the error I get when trying to show the Design view of an `.xml` in *Android Studio*:

[image: Rendering error image]

Comment: Pasting errors and posting screenshot should help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom view and want to avoid render problems, you can wrap your constructor by using `View.isInEditMode()`.

Otherwise make sure to choose select Application theme. It looks like you are trying to render whole screen with text view style. For example you can select, AppCompat.Material.